# Solve equations by using Matrix Inverse Method.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Answer in the book and my answer is different.Can any one help me which one is correct.

```
           Solve the following system of equations by using Matrix Inverse Method.
           3x+ 4y+ 7z= 14
           2x-y+ 3z= 4
           2x + 2y - 3z = 0
```

[Answer form the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTexy.png)

[My Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geh59.png)

Comment: You've confused minor with cofactor.

Comment: can you tell me which one is correct answer from the book or my answer ? thank you so much

Comment: Use [Octave Online](https://octave-online.net/) with MATLAB's syntax to verify.

Comment: Just multiply out both "solutions" by hand.  The wrong answer will quickly reveal itself by plugging in $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from the book is not consistent with the proble. The lower left entry of the matrix should be $2$, not $1$. So, it is normal that whoever wrote it got a different answer.

Comment: I think  left entry matrix should be 2  not 1  ,

Comment: @BishalThapa That's what I meant. Sorry. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That's okay no problem, Can you tell me my answer is correct ?

Comment: @BishalThapa Almost. You computed $A^{-1}$ correctly, but the solution is $\frac{62}{81}$, $\frac{76}{81}$, and $\frac{92}{81}$.

Comment: Thank you so so much @Jose Carlos Santos    You saved me

Answer (score 0):

The best method to check is to plug in the solution in the original system and verify whether or not it work. If not check that $AA^{-1}=I$.